# csv writer is writing blank lines between rows (python 2.7)

Tags: python-2.7, csv

So when I use csv writer to print out a list of arguments it prints blank line between rows.So something like this:

- row 1
- blank line
- row 2
- blank line

My question is what am I doing wrong that makes csv writer produce the blank lines.  Here is my code:

```
row_count = 0
with open(config['LeadImportFilePath']['LeadImportFilePath'] + lead_import_name, 'w') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow(config['Headers']['LeadImportHeaders'].split(','))
    while row_count <= record_rows:
        person_row = [GetCampaignInformation.publisher_id, GetCampaignInformation.source_id, GetPersonInformation.first_name[row_count],
                      GetPersonInformation.last_name[row_count], GetPersonInformation.GetEmail(), GetPersonInformation.phone[row_count],
                      GetCampaignInformation.GetIndustry(), GetCampaignInformation.GetJobTitles(), GetPersonInformation.company_name[row_count],
                      GetPersonInformation.address_1[row_count], GetPersonInformation.address_2[row_count], GetPersonInformation.city[row_count],
                      GetPersonInformation.state[row_count], GetPersonInformation.zip[row_count], GetCampaignInformation.country, GetCampaignInformation.GetCompanySize(),
                      lead_create_date, GetCampaignInformation.ReturnAsset(), campaign_id] + GetCampaignInformation.GetCustomQuestion()
        writer.writerow(person_row)
        row_count += 1
```

I also get this error:
person_row = [GetCampaignInformation.publisher_id, GetCampaignInformation.source_id, GetPersonInformation.first_name[row_count],
IndexError: list index out of range

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding wb instead of w on the with open line like the documentation said to do fixed this problem.  Who knew that python documentation was correct.

```
with open(config['LeadImportFilePath']['LeadImportFilePath'] + lead_import_name, 'wb') as f:
```

Here is the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) for this problem.  Read csv.writer section

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have in CustomQuestion  "\n" in the end.  Remove last char in CustomQuestiom and try again